# NuGet - How to include the application app.config file in the consuming applications build output?

Tags: .net, nuget, packagereference

How can I get my NuGet package to include its app.config in the build output directory of a project that consumes the NuGet package? Currently it is only copying the NuGetConfigInclude.exe but I need it to also have the NuGetConfigInclude.exe.config file. Note the consuming application uses a PackageReference in the .csproj file. It does not use packages.config.

NuGetConfigInclude.nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>NuGetConfigInclude</id>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    <title>NuGetConfigInclude</title>
    <authors>NuGetConfigInclude</authors>
    <owners>NuGetConfigInclude</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>NuGetConfigInclude</description>
    <releaseNotes>Test Summary</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <tags>TEST</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Consuming application project file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NuGetConfigInclude">
      <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

UPDATE:

I have managed to get the nuspec to include the file in the package but on the consuming project it is trying to compile the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>NuGetConfigInclude</id>
    <version>24.0.0.0</version>
    <title>NuGetConfigInclude</title>
    <authors>NuGetConfigInclude</authors>
    <owners>NuGetConfigInclude</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>NuGetConfigInclude</description>
    <releaseNotes>Test Summary</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="contentFiles\any\any\assets\**" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="false" />
    </contentFiles>
    <tags>TEST</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\NuGetConfigInclude.exe.config" target="contentFiles\any\any\assets"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Example Errors when building consuming project:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   NuGetConsumer   C:\Users\GuestAcct.nuget\packages\nugetconfiginclude\24.0.0\contentFiles\any\any\assets\NuGetConfigInclude.exe.config  1   Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>NuGetConfigInclude</id>
    <version>29.0.0.0</version>
    <title>NuGetConfigInclude</title>
    <authors>NuGetConfigInclude</authors>
    <owners>NuGetConfigInclude</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>NuGetConfigInclude</description>
    <releaseNotes>Test Summary</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2020</copyright>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="**/*.*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
    <tags>TEST</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\NuGetConfigInclude.exe.config" target="contentFiles\any\any\"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Important to note that if your consuming project is using PackageReference then the files need to be copied to a folder named contentFiles.